# Adding ListView (images) into GridPane?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, imageview, gridpane

Trying to display images in a thumbnail form to listview in a gridpane

```
 ObservableList<File> imageFiles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 List<File> list = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);

    if(list != null){
        for(File file : list){
            //Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            final Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file), 150, 150, true, false);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            imageView = createImageView(image);

            if(check1.isSelected()){


                VBox vl = new VBox();
                vl.getChildren().addAll(imageView);

                ListView<File> imageFilesList = new ListView<>(imageFiles);
                imageFilesList.setCellFactory(listview -> new ListCell<File>(){
                    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                    {
                        imageView.setFitHeight(80);
                        imageView.setFitWidth(160);
                        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(file, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setText(file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                            imageView.setImage(new Image(file.getAbsolutePath().toString(), true));
                            setGraphic(imageView);
                        }
                    }
                    });

                grid.add(imageFilesList, imageCol, imageRow);
```

I've tried every way I can, this is my output, what am I missing? Why is GridPane still loading it in thumbnail size?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no image shown because,

1) The grid view contains `ListView imageFilesList`, and this list view contains `imageFiles`. But you are not adding any image files to `imageFiles`.
2) The image files chosen via `fileChooser` are added to `VBox vl`. However this vbox is not added to the gridpane.